# Any good math calculators online to find inverse laplace transforms? Specifically $s\log\frac{s+4}{s-4}$

Tags: laplace-transform, calculator, inverse-laplace

I think I have found the final answer $\left(4 \left[\frac{2t \cosh(4t) - \sinh(4t)}{t^2}\right]\right)$ but need to verify it.

Comment: Check this: https://bit.ly/2WOb9J5

Comment: Thank You! Is it possible to find the steps to the solution? I have not understood how the final answer was obtained

Comment: The Bromwich integral diverges. For distributions, $\mathcal L[f'] = s \mathcal L[f]$. Then
$$\mathcal L^{-1} {\left[ \ln \frac {s + 4} {s - 4} \right]} =
\frac {2 \sinh 4 t} t, \\
\mathcal L^{-1} {\left[ s \ln \frac {s + 4} {s - 4} \right]} =
\frac d {dt} \frac {2 \sinh 4 t} t =
\frac {8 t \cosh 4 t - 2 \sinh 4 t} {t^2} + 8 \delta(t).$$

Comment: @AdityaRamesh See the answer, please. Also the Maxim's comment answers your question.

Comment: @AdityaRamesh It seems you've asked the same question three times. So it's better to delete other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$F(s) = s\ln\frac{s+4}{s-4}$$
The first property to use is $$\mathcal L[g'] = s\mathcal L[g] - g(0^-)$$
So we consider $\mathcal L[g] = \ln\frac{s+4}{s-4}$. Another property is $$\mathcal L[\frac{h(t)}{t}] = \int_s^\infty H(\lambda)d\lambda$$
Where $\mathcal L[h] = H(s)$. Note that $$\int_s^\infty (\frac{1}{\lambda - 4} - \frac{1}{\lambda + 4})d\lambda = \ln\frac{s+4}{s-4}$$
So $H(s) = \frac{1}{s - 4} - \frac{1}{s + 4}$ and that implies $$h(t) = e^{4t} - e^{-4t}$$
Therefore $g(t) = \frac{e^{4t} - e^{-4t}}{t}$. Then $$\lim_{t \to 0} g(t) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^{4t} - e^{-4t}}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{4e^{4t} +4e^{-4t}}{1} = 8$$
Note that $$\mathcal L[\delta] = 1$$ Finally $$f(t) = g'(t) + 8\delta(t) = \frac{t(4e^{4t} + 4e^{-4t}) - (e^{4t} - e^{-4t})}{t^2} + 8\delta(t)$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Previously did not understand how the Dirac Delta function came about, but this has cleared my doubt. Appreciate it a ton.

Comment: @AdityaRamesh You're welcome. You can accept that if you want.