# Math calculators to find inverse laplace transform of slightly complicated equation

Tags: laplace-transform

I have found out the inverse laplace of $\log\frac{s+4}{s-4}$ which is $\frac{2 sinh(4t)}{t}$
But I do not know how to proceed. The multiplication by s property does not seem to hold good here as the denominator has t, which would imply f(0) would be 0/0
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I think I have found the final answer ($4 [\frac{2t cosh(4t) - sinh(4t)}{t^2}]$, but need to verify it. Could anyone suggest any math calculator which gives answers to inverse laplace transform questions?

Comment: you could try https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform+of+log%28%28s%2B4%29%2F%28s-4%29%29

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any good math calculators online to find inverse laplace transforms? Specifically $s\log\frac{s+4}{s-4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683997/any-good-math-calculators-online-to-find-inverse-laplace-transforms-specificall)